# Spring-boot-starter-upgrade-3.0 SAML sso issues

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-saml

Problem :
Initially we wrote spring boot app using spring-boot-starter-parent version - 2.0.5.RELEASE. As part of the
app we need SAML SSO so we used spring-security-saml2-core with the version - 1.0.3.RELEASE

Currently it was required for us to upgrade the app and upgraded spring-boot-starter-parent version to - 2.7.9. When we upgraded spring-boot-starter-parent to 2.7.9 the SAML SSO is working fine without any code changes or without upgrading spring-security-saml2-core. The SAML SSO working fine with (spring-boot-starter-parent version - 2.7.9 and spring-security-saml2-core - 1.0.3.RELEASE)

Also we decided to upgrade the app with (spring-boot-starter-parent to 3.0 with JDK 17 and spring-security-saml2-core to 1.0.10.RELEASE). We were able to compile all the source code. When we run the app we are encountering run time issues related incompatible imports on **javax/servlet/ServletResponse** and **jakarta/servlet/ServletResponse**. It seems spring upgrade servlet API's are referring from **jakarta/servlet/ServletResponse** so we updated where the import updates are required.  Where as in spring dependencies we still see they are referring from **javax/servlet/ServletResponse **due to which it is becoming to incompatible version in our code.

My Question - After analysis it seems some major challenges migrating app to spring 3.0 with with JDK 17 and spring-security-saml2-core to 1.0.10.RELEASE.

Any thoughts or inputs or some guidance is helpful.

Comment: Did you get any solution for the question? I am also facing similar challenge in my project. Any guidance on how you solved or still a question?

Comment: https://github.com/gtiwari333/spring-security-saml-test-identity-provider-and-service-provider check this out. I've implemented SP initiated SSO flow with Spring Boot 3.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have found the solution aldy. You may need to change the package to spring-security-saml2-service-provider because even in  1.0.10.RELEASE version, jakarta EE is not supported yet.

Comment: https://github.com/gtiwari333/spring-security-saml-test-identity-provider-and-service-provider check this out. I've implemented SP initiated SSO flow with Spring Boot 3.